# How to migrate User database from FBA to AD in SP2010

Tags: authentication, active-directory, user-profile-service

I have successfully migrated from WSS 3.0 to SP2010.

The User database is FBA.

However, I need to migrate from FBA to Active Directory (AD).

I need to know the process to migrate this User Database from FBA to AD in SP2010. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

saumil

PS - What advantages does AD have over FBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a CSV file from your FBA user store (somehow), and import that into AD using the Active Directory Users and Groups interface.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

I have migrated User DB (FBA) to SP2010 using Claim based Authentication already.

Now, I want to change FBA to Active Directory.

My Questions

    How to change from FBA to AD?
    Do I need to change authentication if I need AD? 

 :)

Comment: Forgot about trying a bulk import, good answer James :-)

As far as how to change it from FBA to AD, the settings are in Central Administration for the Web Application.  Yes you will need to change the authentication, you get more details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A quick search has revealed nothing out of the box or third party available for this.  However likely you could script something since there are plenty of API's that interact with Active Directory, you would have to:

1) Pull all information out of your Forms based provider (be it SQL Server, XML File, FaceBook, etc.)

2) One at a time, use the active directory API's to create new logins.

Sorry but I don't see an easier way here.

Also as far as advantages, you are using a proven method of securely storing logins that can be used elsewhere within windows with ease, such as Windows Login, SQL Server Login, Kerberos delegation, etc.  But it's really apples vs. oranges going from FBA to AD.